# Is it possible to compile complie seperate module that depend on only one library in SASS?

Tags: sass

For example, a lot of the SASS  I have been writing require and use the mixins from bootstrap. However, I would like everything to not be complied into one large file. So for example in a main.scss I could have:

```
@import 'bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';
@import '_mypage'
@import '_mypage2'
```

but when you compile the file it would just end up as one file where I am trying to get it so I have bootstrap, mypage, and mypag2 as separate css file, while maintain the ability to use the bootstrap.

Is there a way to do this in sass? Or should I be looking at certain tools to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the `_` in front of SCSS files is what tells the compiler **not** to make its own file. What you're telling the compiler with your `@import` lines is that you want all of those files to be added to the top of your `main.scss`.

If you make a `mypage.scss`, and put it in the same directory where the compiler is looking, it will compile to its own file. You can either import bootstrap at the top of that file as well, or just load earlier it in your HTML to be able to reference it.